# Not Populating list in HTML with Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, rss, browserify

I am learning Javascript. I am working on reading RSS feeds for a personal project. I am using 'RSS-parser' npm library to avoid CORS error.
And also I am using Browserify bundler to make it work on the browser.

When I run this code on the terminal it gives me output without any issue. But when I try with the browser it prints nothing.

My knowledge about Asynchronous JS is limited but I am pretty sure it doesn't have errors in here as I added code to it without changing existing code.

```
let Parser = require('rss-parser');
let parser = new Parser();

let feed;
async () => {

  feed = await parser.parseURL('https://www.reddit.com/.rss');
  feedTheList();
};


// setTimeout(function() {
//   //your code to be executed after 1 second
//   feedTheList();

// }, 5000);


function feedTheList()
{
  document.body.innerHTML = "<h1>Total Feeds: " + feed.items.length + "</h1>";


    let u_list = document.getElementById("list")[0];

    feed.items.forEach(item => {



        var listItem = document.createElement("li");

        //Add the item text
        var newText = document.createTextNode(item.title);
        listItem.appendChild(newText);
        listItem.innerHTML =item.title;

        //Add listItem to the listElement
        u_list.appendChild(listItem);

    });
}
```

Here is my HTML code.

```
<body>

     <ul id="list"></ul>
     <script src="bundle.js"></script>
</body>
```

Any guidance is much appreciated.

Comment: Any console errors?
Hard to say. I would open a developer tools, network tab, verify that results are coming, and then make sure that this code runs after `DOMContentLoaded`  event, otherwise `document.body` may not be available yet. `document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded",function(){//yourcode
});` -- a quick and easy way to check this also is just place your script at the very bottom of your page, as is. This will ensure it runs after DOM is loaded. And, if the network tab shows result RSS is not coming, then something with `browserify` and `rss-parser` may be the problem.

Comment: @DmitriyKhaykin no console errors.

Comment: @DmitriyKhaykin `feed` is empty.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Looks like the async call is not being executed; You need to wrap it
>   in an anonymous function call:

See the example here:
https://www.npmjs.com/package/rss-parser

Essentially,

```
var feed; // change let to var, so feed can be used inside the function
// wrap the below into a function call 
(async () => {
  feed = await parser.parseURL('https://www.reddit.com/.rss');
  feedTheList();
})(); // the (); at the end executes the promise
```

Now it will execute and `feed` should have items.

> CORS errors when making request

As noted in the documentation at https://www.npmjs.com/package/rss-parser, if you get CORS error on a resource, use a CORS proxy. I've updated their example to fit your code:

```
// Note: some RSS feeds can't be loaded in the browser due to CORS security.
// To get around this, you can use a proxy.
const CORS_PROXY = "https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/"

let parser = new RSSParser();
(async () => {
    await parser.parseURL(CORS_PROXY + 'https://www.reddit.com/.rss', function(err, feed) {    
        feedTheList(feed);
    });
})();

function feedTheList(feed)
{
    // unchanged
}
```

One last thing:
The line

```
document.body.innerHTML = "<h1>Total Feeds: " + feed.items.length + "</h1>";
```

Will remove all of the content of `<body>`

I suggest to look into how `element.appendChild` works, or just place the `<h1>` tag in your HTML and modify its `innerHTML` property instead.

Comment: That is covered in the docs I linked, and there is a workaround. I'll add to my answer.

Comment: Now I am getting all the item data. But list is not getting populated. No errors.

Comment: And change `let u_list` to `var u_list;`, since `let` is intended for the immediate scope only, but you are creating that variable and then using it inside a function where it does not have scope.

Answer (score 2):

`document.getElementById()` returns a single element, not a collection, so you don't need to index it. So this:

```
let u_list = document.getElementById("list")[0];
```

sets `u_list` to `undefined, and you should be getting errors later in the code. It should just be:

```
let u_list = document.getElementById("list");
```

Also, when you do:

```
listItem.innerHTML =item.title;
```

it will replace the text node that you appended on the previous line with this HTML. Either append the text node or assign to `innerHTML` (or more correctly, `innerText`), you don't need to do both.

Comment: Did changes as you mentioned but Still nothing showing on the browser.

Comment: Are you getting any errors in the JavaScript console?

Comment: No errors. Also I have basic html file nothing fancy. Only unordered list.

Comment: If you put `console.log(feed.items)` in `feedTheList`, do you see the expected result?

Comment: feed.items is empty.

Comment: So you're seeing `Total feeds: 0`?

Comment: Nothing is showing in console. I tried console.log(feed.items) and also the Total feeds but its not showing up.

Comment: Are you sure the `feedTheList()` function is even being called?

Comment: You are right. function is not going called. I guess await is taking much time. But that in that case it shoud show some errors like if I have that function call outside async call

Comment: Use the Network tab of the console to see if the AJAX request is getting a response.

Comment: Yes I am getting response in the network but it is also giving me CORS errors. To avoid that I was using the library.

Comment: Why do you think using the library fixes CORS problems? The documentation says to get around CORS you should use a proxy.

Comment: Thanks for guiding me. It turned out that I made stupid mistakes. Thanks for pointing it out.